# Fail to get unicode URL in IIS 6

Tags: iis, unicode

I setup an IIS server running at localhost and put 2 file with unicode file name, for e.g:

```
변태연.txt and 변태연.flv
```

The 2 files are all real but only 1 working:

```
localhost/변태연.txt
```

I don't know why? Do u guys have any idea ab this problem?

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

At a guess it sounds like your web server might not have the correct mime type installed for `.flv` files.

You need to create this before the server will serve `.flv` files on IIS6:

```
.flv => video/x-flv
```